# exit from a hybrid app using vue.js and cordova

Tags: cordova, vue.js, mobile, hybrid

When I switch from the current page to the previous one I keep the history in my android app, but when I go the home page and try to exit the app the android exit button doesn't function.

I used event bus(vue.js and cordova).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve], as without code we can only guess what you did.